# How to sort or resolve Hibernate XML error? Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, jdbc

when I run the main class the compiler gets some errors and the errors are written below.
This is very difficult to sort i totally waste four than more hours.
**This is the hibernate.cfg.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connction.password">Kunal@1234@</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**This is main class**

```
package com.hona.hoja;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Project Started..." );
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println(factory);
        System.out.println(factory.isClosed());
}
}
```

**I got ERROR below so how i can resolve?**

```
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.4.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:260)
    at com.hona.hoja.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,64]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:104)
    ... 5 more
```

I will consider XML formatted file hibernate.cfg.xml to specify required Hibernate properties in my examples. Most of the properties take their default values and it is not required to specify them in the property file unless it is really required. This file is kept in the root directory of your application's classpath.

Comment: You did not paste the xml file.

Comment: I pasted hibernate.cfg.xml file above see

Comment: There is no xml file there. It's your Java code twice.

Comment: Thank you it's my mistake i will change in few hours.

Comment: Now you can please see the XML file and tell me what I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is even telling you the offending line (line 3).

I use annotations myself, but your `DOCTYPE` has one fewer argument than the sample file I found on the web.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below `DOCTYPE` in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```